# Prove that in a tree #leaves + #nodes of degree 2 $\geq \frac{n}{2}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $T = (V,E)$ be a Tree with $n = |V|$ nodes.

Let $b$ denote the number of leaves and $z$ the number of nodes with degree $2$.

I want to show that 
$$
b + z \geq \frac{n}{2}.
$$

I want to use the Handshake lemma
$$
\sum_{v \in V} \deg(v) = 2 | E | = 2(n-1),
$$
but this hasn't brought me far.

---

**EDIT**

Using the suggestion from @Batominovski:

We know there are $n - b -z$ nodes with degree at least three.
The handshake lemma thus gives:
$$
b + 2z + 3(n - b - z) \leq \sum_{v \in V} \deg(v) = 2(n - 1)
$$
Simplification yields
$$
-2b - z + 3n \leq 2n - 2,
$$
and further
$$
n + 2 \leq 2b + z.
$$
Finally
$$
\frac{n}{2} + 1 \leq b + \frac{z}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**  We have a stronger inequality $b+\dfrac{z}{2}\geq \dfrac{n}{2}+1$ if $n>1$ (where the equality holds if and only if the maximum degree of $T$ is at most $3$).  Show that $$b+2z+3(n-b-z)\leq \sum\limits_{v\in V}\,\deg(v)\,.$$

Comment: I proved that inequality hours before posting but didn't think it would help... Thanks for showing me, that I was on the right track!